# Tabular 2 column issue: Misplaced \noalign

Tags: tables

I was previously using 3 columns. I switched to 2 columns, formatted everything to fit, and the table broke.

I cannot find a way to fix it, can someone help me to find and solve the issue?

**Minimal Reproducible Example** (compiled with Overleaf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}

\author{mikyll}
\title{test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{0.2\linewidth}|p{0.7\linewidth}| }
        \hline
        \centering{\textbf{Feature}} & \centering{\textbf{Description}}\\
        \hline
        CORS control & test\\
        \hline
        Rate Limiting & test \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{API Gateway Requirements.}
    \label{tab:api-gateway-requirements}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Error:

[image]

```
31: Misplaced \noalign
32: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
```

Comment: Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: A minor comment: To make your code *minimally compilable*, it's not necessary to load the `graphicx`, `subcaption`, `hyperref`, `comment`, `svg`, and `multirow` packages.

Comment: @Mico love that, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instruction `\centering{\textbf{Description}}` creates the error message. Since I can't see a good reason for wanting to center the contents of the header cells, I'd get rid of the `\centering` directives. (If, for some reason, you simply must center the contents of the right-hand header cell, simply replace `\textbf{Description}` with `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Description}}`.

I'd also switch to a `tabularx` setup and set the target width of the table to `\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped look

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | 
    >{\RaggedRight}p{0.2\linewidth} | % suppress full justification
    >{\RaggedRight}X | } % suppress full justification
\hline
\textbf{Feature} & \textbf{Description} \\
\hline
CORS control     & test \\
\hline
Rate Limiting    & test \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\caption{API Gateway Requirements.}
\label{tab:api-gateway-requirements}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```